# c++ STL unordered_map error , invalid argument type while using method "find"

Tags: c++

I am a student very new to c++ and I am currently stuck on this one problem.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
    unordered_map<char,int> um;
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if(!um.find(s.at(i))) {
            um.insert(make_pair(s[i],i));
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

int main() {
    cout << lengthOfLongestSubstring("bbbbb") <<endl; // should return 1
    cout << lengthOfLongestSubstring("abcabcbb") << endl; // should return 3
    cout << lengthOfLongestSubstring("pwwkew") << endl; // should return 3
}
```

While coding, I am keep getting error message in the condition checking **um.find(s.at(i))**,
problem of which I cannot quit get hold of.

Can any one tell me a good solution to this?
+ is there any better way to code this problem more efficiently?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Why do you insert `i` into map but do not use it?

Comment: For future reference, it's a good idea to mention when the error shows up - e.g. at compile time vs. link time vs. run time.

Comment: "I am keep getting error message" don't tell that error message to anybody, that would make it more interesting for people to solve.

Answer (score 2):

```
 if(!um.find(s.at(i))) {
```

`find()` returns an iterator, and not a boolean value, and iterators are not convertible to `bool`.

Although you can compare the return iterator to the `end()`ing, or perhaps use `count()`, there's a much simpler approach:

```
    if (!um.insert(make_pair(s[i],i)).second)
        break;
```

That's it. See your C++ textbook's explanation of what `insert()` returns, and why and how this works.

P.S., the third test case should return 2.

Comment: You should mention that there is no point to insert `i` as a value. That would get rid of `make_pair()` and simplifies the code. In real life application it would be even cheaper to use bool array with 256 elements, rather than hash set/map.

Answer (score 0):

The member function `find` returns an iterator for which the operator ! is not defined.

```
iterator find(const key_type& k);
const_iterator find(const key_type& k) const;
```

Instead of the member function `find` use the member function `count`.

```
if(!um.count(s.at(i))) {
```

that is declared like

```
size_type count(const key_type& k) const;
```

Pay attention to that the output will be

```
1
3
2
```

Answer (score 0):

`find()` returns an iterator, which is not convertible to `bool`, so you can't use it like `if (!um.find(s.at(i)))`. Per the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find), `find()` returns `end()` if the element isn't found in the map. So you need to do this:

```
if(um.find(s.at(i)) == um.end()) {
    um.insert(make_pair(s[i],i));
} else {
    break;
}
```

Alternatively, note that [insert()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) doesn't add the element if it already exists, and tells you whether it does via the return value (a `pair<iterator, bool>`). So your code can just be:

```
if (!um.insert(make_pair(s[i], i)).second) {
    break;
}
```